# How to get role of SPGroup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, groups, roles

I wrote the following code:

```
SPGroup spGroupItem = web.SiteGroups["Site Owners"];
SPPrincipal principal = spGroupItem;
SPRoleAssignment oRoleAssignment = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(principal);
foreach (SPRoleDefinition inRole in oRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(inRole.Name);
      }
```

But this code gives following exception for some groups.

> Can not find the principal with id: xxx

Comment: where are you getting spweb object ?  try using the web object within the  runwithelevatedprivielges :                                                                                    try {
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strSite))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {

Comment: try this too: SPPrincipal pr = SPContext.Current.Web.Groups[0];

if (pr is SPGroup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group");
}

Answer (score 1):

There can be some attributes missing for the groups/users. Cross check the properties of the group along with other groups. Is it custom permission level defined group which is throwing this exception?